# php recursive get parents

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, parents

I am trying to get jquery.treeview.js to fold out to the just created folder. Think I need an array of "parents" to set class to "open".

Other suggestions works with me ;-) (find this a bit too much but cannot find another way to do it.

Having an array like this:

```
    array(7) {
      [126]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(3) "126"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(3) "555"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(3) "125"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(14) "Administration"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(5) "Britt"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "2"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(9) "Documents"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "3"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(14) "Infrastructure"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(4) "root"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [125]=>
      array(4) {
        ["folder_id"]=>
        string(3) "125"
        ["folder_name"]=>
        string(13) "test-deleteme"
        ["folder_parent"]=>
        string(1) "7"
      }
    }
```

I would like to get the parents from selected folder_id.

getting data for folder_id=126 should return an array with parents {1,2,7,122}

Anyone?

Comment: you mean {1,2,7,125}?

Comment: Sorry, yes, your are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, here is mine with recursive:

```
function getParent($folder_id, $data, $parents=array()) {
    $parent_id = isset($data[$folder_id]) ? $data[$folder_id]['folder_parent'] : 0;
    if ($parent_id > 0) {
        array_unshift($parents, $parent_id);
        return getParent($parent_id, $data, $parents);
    }
    return $parents;
}

//Usage
print_r(getParent(126, $your_folders));
```

It seems like I had plagiarized [mancuernita's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350909/534862) I hereby apologize. It's just similar, but I'm not copying!

Comment: Probably we all thought of a similar solution when we read the question ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm. (except the usage changed to getParent)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
function yourFunction(id, array) {
  sol = array();
  while (id) {
    id = find_parent(id, array);
    array_push(sol, id);
  }

  return sol;
}

function find_parent(id, array) {
  return array[id]["folder_parent"];
}
```

I haven't tried the code, and probably it needs some work more.

Comment: Definitely looks more like pseudo-code than PHP.